# Why won't the exp function work in pyspark?

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, exp

I'm trying to calculate odds ratios from the coefficients of a logistic regression but I'm encountering a problem best summed up by this code:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F 
F.exp(1.2)
```

This fails with 
`py4j.Py4JException: Method exp([class java.lang.Double]) does not exist`

An integer fails similarly. I don't get how a Double can cause a problem for the exp function?

Comment: The exp function will work on a `pyspark.sql.functions.col` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a look at the documentation for [`pyspark.sql.functions.exp()`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.exp), it takes an input of a col object. Hence it will not work for a float value such as `1.2`.

Create a dataframe or a `Column` object which you can use in `F.exp()`

Example would be:

```
df = df.withColumn("exp_x", F.exp(F.col("some_col_named_x")))
```

Answer (score 0):

As @pissall mentionned, the `pyspark.sql.functions.exp` takes col objects as parameter, but you can use the `pyspark.sql.functions.lit` (introduced in version `1.3.0`) to create a `col` object of a literal value.

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import exp, lit

df = df.withColumn("exp_1", exp(lit(1)))
```